# Laravel middleware 'except' rule not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have a controller with the following in the constructor:

```
$this->middleware('guest', ['except' =>
    [
        'logout',
        'auth/facebook',
        'auth/facebook/callback',
        'auth/facebook/unlink'
    ]
]);
```

The 'logout' rule (which is there by default) works perfectly but the other 3 rules I have added are ignored. The routes in `routes.php` look like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']],function(){

    Route::auth();

    // Facebook auth
    Route::get('/auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToFacebook')->name('facebook_auth');
    Route::get('/auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleFacebookCallback')->name('facebook_callback');
    Route::get('/auth/facebook/unlink', 'Auth\AuthController@handleFacebookUnlink')->name('facebook_unlink');
}
```

If I visit `auth/facebook`, `auth/facebook/callback` or `auth/facebook/unlink` whilst logged in I get denied by the middleware and thrown back to the homepage.

I've tried specifying the 'except' rules with proceeding `/`'s so they match the routes in `routes.php` exactly but it makes no difference. Any ideas why these rules are being ignored, whilst the default 'logout' rule is respected?

Cheers!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to pass the method's name instead of the URI.

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => [
            'redirectToFacebook', 'handleFacebookCallback', 'handleFacebookUnlink'
        ]]);
    }
}
```

Since Laravel 5.3, you can use fluent interface to define middlewares on controllers, which seems cleaner than using multidimensional arrays.

```php
<?php

$this->middleware('guest')->except('redirectToFacebook', 'handleFacebookCallback', 'handleFacebookUnlink');
```

Comment: Any other ideas? Have done this, tried different syntaxes and variations, but it still redirects. The route has a name, and the name is listed in the `except` array. Considering to hack the RedirectIfAuthenticated class as a workaround. Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue in my Middleware by adding this `inExceptArray` function. It's the same way `VerifyCsrfToken` handles the except array.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Routes that should skip handle.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/some/route',
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the request has a URI that should pass through.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function inExceptArray($request)
    {
        foreach ($this->except as $except) {
            if ($except !== '/') {
                $except = trim($except, '/');
            }

            if ($request->is($except)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // check user authed or API Key
        if (!$this->inExceptArray($request)) {
            // Process middleware checks and return if failed...
            if (true) {
              // Middleware failed, send back response
              return response()->json([
                'error' => true,
                'Message' => 'Failed Middleware check'
            ]); 
            }
        }
        // Middleware passed or in Except array
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to follow the Laravel Documentation, an alternative solution to this is suggested by adding routes to the $except variable in the /Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file. The documentation says to add them like this:

```
'route/*'
```

But I found the only way to get it to work is by putting the routes to ignore like this:

```
'/route'
```

Answer (score 2):

When assigning middleware to a group of routes, you may occasionally need to prevent the middleware from being applied to an individual route within the group. You may accomplish this using the withoutMiddleware method:

```
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAge;

Route::middleware([CheckAge::class])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        //
    });

    Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
        //
    })->withoutMiddleware([CheckAge::class]);
});
```

for more information read [documentation laravel middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function in your Controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth' => 'verified'])->except("page_name_1", "page_name_2", "page_name_3");
    }
```

*replace page_name_1/2/3 with yours.

For me it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solved, and here's what I am doing. Aso, I just realized this is very similar to what **cmac** did in his answer.

*api.php*

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/user', 'Auth\UserController@me')->name('me');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

*LoginController.php*

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    // ...

    /**
     * If the user's session is expired, the auth token is already invalidated,
     * so we just return success to the client.
     *
     * This solves the edge case where the user clicks the Logout button as their first
     * interaction in a stale session, and allows a clean redirect to the login page.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->guard()->user();

        if ($user) {
            $this->guard()->logout();
            JWTAuth::invalidate();
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Logged out.'], 200);
    }
}
```

*Authenticate.php*

```php
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Exclude these routes from authentication check.
     *
     * Note: `$request->is('api/fragment*')` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/logout',
    ];

    /**
     * Ensure the user is authenticated.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            foreach ($this->except as $excluded_route) {
                if ($request->path() === $excluded_route) {
                    \Log::debug("Skipping $excluded_route from auth check...");
                    return  $next($request);
                }
            }

            // code below here requires 'auth'

        { catch ($e) {
            // ...
        }

    }
```

I over-engineered it slightly. Today I only need an exemption on `/api/logout`, but I set the logic up to quickly add more routes. If you research the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, you'll see it takes a form like this:

```php
    protected $except = [
        'api/logout',
        'api/foobars*',
        'stripe/poop',
        'https://www.external.com/yolo',
    ];
```

That's why I put that "note" in my doc above there. `$request->path() === $excluded_route` will probably not match `api/foobars*`, but `$request->is('api/foobars*')` should. Additionally, a person might be able to use something like `$request->url() === $excluded_route` to match `http://www.external.com/yolo`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the function name to 'except'.

Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
$this->middleware('IsAdminOrSupport', ['except' => [
        'ProductsByShopPage'
        ]
    ]);
```

This means the middleware 'IsAdminOrSupport' is applied to all methods of this controller except for the method 'ProductByShopPage'.