# I need to make auth on all resource controller except show class

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make auth on all resource controller except show class

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('pdfs', PdfController::class);
});
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel middleware 'except' rule not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711134/laravel-middleware-except-rule-not-working)

Comment: i want to make every page request login first except the show page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can achieve it with something like this in your route:

```
Route::resource('pdfs', PdfController::class)->only(['show']);

Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('pdfs', PdfController::class)->except(['show']);
});
```

**Option 2:** You can write a route without the middleware like bellow:

```
Route::resource('pdfs', PdfController::class)
```

And in your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware([
        'auth:sanctum',
        config('jetstream.auth_session'),
        'verified'
    ])->except(['show']);
}
```